# how to append svg element included <a>, <title> in div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried append svg element included `<a>`, `<title>` in a `<div>` tag. Rectangular object created by `<g>` tag shows in the screen where it should be.

The problem is I want to use `<a>` and `<title>` tag with `<g>` so when I point cursor on my object title will appear.

The structure is

```
<div>
  <svg>
    <a>
      <title></title>
      <g>
        <rect>
      </g>
    </a>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This structure works when I use it without jQuery, but when I use `append(``), the``and`` tag seem to mess up.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mapping"></div>


<script>
  var o = "<svg height=\"601\" width=\"1301\><g><a href=\"index.html\"><title>DESTINATION1</title><rect x = \"660\" y = \"190\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" style=\"fill:rgb(255,255,0)\" /></a></g></svg>";
  $("#mapping").append(o);
</script>
```

[a and g tag not working on append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnAbR.png)

The below code works fine (when not using jQuery)

```html
<div>
  <svg height="601" width="1301">
    <g>
      <a href="#">
        <title>Obstacle1</title> 
        <rect x="650" y="160" width="130" height="150" style="fill: grey; fill-opacity: 0.9; stroke: white; stroke-width: 0.5"/>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[a and g tag work fine without append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA1F0.png)

Comment: Please take care to format your questions properly. This was unreadable before I edited it.

Comment: Also note the problem is because you're missing a `"` after the `width=\"1301`, and possibly other places, but I stopped there. Alternate quotes types instead of escaping them and the code becomes much clearer, eg. `var o = '<svg height="601" width="1301">...`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: I tried it here and looks fine. What is the timing you are calling this?  https://jsfiddle.net/zug0r4ny/1/

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll be more careful. It's my first time. and thank to you Rory.